# how to check whether a string have stars followed by four digit number?

Tags: javascript

I have a random string which is getting from database. A string might be any length. I need to check whether a string should be in this pattern like `*******1234`. A string can have any number of stars (*) with four digit number. How do I check that?

Comment: Use a regular expression? `\*\d{4}`

Answer (score 3):

To check if a string starts with asterisks and ends with 4 digits, use this regexp:

```js
const exp = new RegExp('^\\*+\\d{4}$');

console.log(exp.test('***1234')) // true;
console.log(exp.test('***12345')) // false
console.log(exp.test('****234')) // false
console.log(exp.test('***d1234')) // false
console.log(exp.test('a***1234')) // false
```

- `^`: start of string
- `\*+`: match at least one asterisk
- `\d{4}`: match exactly 4 digits
- `$`: end of string

Answer (score 2):

You can try RegEx `/^\*{1,}\d{4}/`.

**Where**

`^` starts the matching at the beginning of the string

`\*{1,}` matches the character `*` literally between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\d{4}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) exactly 4 times

With [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns `true` or `false`.

```js
function checkString(str){
  return /^\*{1,}\d{4}/.test(str);
}
console.log(checkString('*******1234'));
console.log(checkString('*******12'));
console.log(checkString('34*******1234'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can perform the task with two ways, First with regular expression and other with below :

```
var id = "ctl03_Tabs1";
var lastFive = id.substr(id.length - 5); // => "Tabs1"
var lastChar = id.substr(id.length - 1); // =>
```